# Passing a shell variable into an awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a loop that processes a bunch of files within a dir. I would like to input the filename into the file it processes, but I'm getting an error. It works perfectly with the `myvar` syntax but I need that for obvious reasons.

## Error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: RS=
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

## Command

```
for filename in $files
do
    awk -v "myvar=${filename}" 
      RS= '/-- Ticket/{++i; print "PROMPT myvar Line ", 
      i ORS $0 ORS; i+=split($0, a, /\n/)+1}' ${filename}.txt
done
```

Comment: `awk -v myvar="$filename" -v RS= '/-- Ticket/{++i; print "PROMPT", myvar, "Line ", i ORS $0 ORS; i+=split($0, a, /\n/)+1}' "$filename.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here, use the `-v` syntax for each of the variables that you are trying to pass to `awk`,

```
awk -v myvar="${filename}" -v RS= '/-- Ticket/{++i; print "PROMPT " myvar " Line ", i ORS $0 ORS; i+=split($0, a, /\n/)+1}' ${filename}.txt
#  ^^^ variable1           ^^^^^ variable2 --> using separate -v for each
```

should be right approach.

For a shell variable import to `awk` do it as in my example above, not as `"myvar=${filename}"` but just `myvar="${filename}"`

Comment: Yeah I did try this approach and the error I got is: `awk: cmd. line:1: RS=
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ unexpected newline or end of string`

Comment: @luckytaxi: try it exactly as in my answer.

Comment: Right, ok so i had to put `PROMPT myvar Line ` but it's not printing `myvar`

Comment: @luckytaxi: Refer my update, try `awk -v myvar="${filename}" -v RS= '/-- Ticket/{++i; print "PROMPT "myvar" Line ", i ORS $0 ORS; i+=split($0, a, /\n/)+1}' ${filename}.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you could avoid a batch loop, it's better (performance mainly for subshell fork, ...)

```
# assume TXT_files is the list of $files with .txt extension (not purpose of this OP)
awk RS='' '
   /-- Ticket/{
     # get the file name without extension
     myvar = FILENAME;sub( /\.txt$/,"",myvar)

     print "PROMPT " myvar " Line " ++i ORS $0 ORS

     i += split( $0, a, /\n/) + 1
     }
   ' ${TXT_files}
```